# Flask web app get 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, flask

Hello world I am writing a web application that gets information from API by passing a variable to the link to get its result and passing it to another link to get the final information to display it to the user, but this error continues to appear

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\users\dreamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 2447, in wsgi_app
> response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "c:\users\dreamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "c:\users\dreamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1821, in handle_user_exception
> reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "c:\users\dreamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py",
> line 39, in reraise
> raise value   File "c:\users\dreamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "c:\users\dreamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1936, in dispatch_request
> return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint   File "C:\Users\DREAMER\Desktop\project\app.py", line 50, in index
> name1 = movie["name"] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

This is my code
helpers.py

```
def lookupid(gen):
    """Look up for Movies."""

    url = "https://imdb8.p.rapidapi.com/title/get-popular-movies-by-genre"

    querystring = {"genre":"/chart/popular/genre/adventure"}

    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-key': "d3c73c113emsh184235f8b4d5bc2p1bd515jsnf605a891b776",
        'x-rapidapi-host': "imdb8.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

    # Contact API
    try:
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.RequestException:
        return None

    # Parse response
    try:
        text = response.json()
        r = random.randint(0, 100)
        tit = text[r].split("/")[1:-1]
        return tit[1]

    except (KeyError, TypeError, ValueError):
        return None


def lookupm(m_id):
    #---------------- Overview Information ---------------- t[r]

    url = "https://imdb8.p.rapidapi.com/title/get-overview-details"

    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-key': "d3c73c113emsh184235f8b4d5bc2p1bd515jsnf605a891b776",
        'x-rapidapi-host': "imdb8.p.rapidapi.com"
    }
    querystring = {"tconst":"{m_id}"}

    # Contact API
    try:
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.RequestException:
        return None

    # Parse response
    try:
        over = response.json()
        return {
            "name": over["title"]["title"],
            "imgurl": over["title"]["image"]["url"],
            "type": over["title"]["titleType"],
            "year": over["title"]["year"],
            "summary": over["plotSummary"]["text"],
            "genres": over["genres"]
        }

    except (KeyError, TypeError, ValueError):
        return None
```

app.py

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("home.html")
    else:
        mood = request.form["mood"]
        titleid = lookupid(mood)
        movie = lookupm(titleid)
        name1 = movie["name"]
        imgurl = movie["imgurl"]
        type1 = movie["type"]
        year = movie["year"]
        summary = movie["summary"]
        genres = movie["genres"]
        return render_template("index.html", name=name1, imgurl=imgurl, type1=type1, year=year, summary=summary, genres=genres)
```

I take the first variable (gen) from the user by radio input.
I do not know where the point of error is or I cannot discover it. Any help. I will be grateful for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `lookupm` returns `None` if errors happen in it, and you never check what `lookupm` is returning to ensure that it isn't `None` before using it. `except (KeyError, TypeError, ValueError):` is probably not a good idea. That's blindly catching very broad, unrelated errors.

Comment: Try adding print statements to your `except` clauses in your `lookupm()` function as it is returning `None`

Comment: This error means that `movie` is `None`, so it cannot be subscripted like `movie[‘name’]`. Thus, the line `movie = lookupm(titleid)` must be returning nothing from the API call.

Comment: @Carcigenicate   so i should remove except and see what return from api

Comment: Yes, I would double check the data to ensure that you're parsing it correctly. That `except` may be appropriate if you know for sure that how you're processing the data is correct, and that the site sometimes returns malformed data. Until you've verified the correctness of the logic though, that `except` is potentially covering up bugs in your code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you

Answer (score 0):

the solution was in delete exception to know where is the error and change:

```
querystring = {"tconst":"{m_id}"}
```

to

```
querystring = {"tconst":{m_id}}
```